# Mobile chat's "Stay on Bottom" behavior is extremely annoying

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, mobile-web

I figured the "stay on bottom" option in mobile chat meant that when a new post was posted, chat would keep you stuck at the bottom of the convo; how useful! Instead, what it does is kick you back to the bottom of the screen every couple seconds, resulting in *extremely* aggravating scrolling behavior until you notice what's up.

Could this be changed to be more in-line with normal chat, so "stay at bottom" just means "when there's a new post"? Because the current default is extremely frustrating and unexpected behavior which makes scrolling impossible. Defaults should never be *annoying* because a fair amount of people won't bother to or know that they can turn them off.

Comment: Seconded.. It took me a while to figure out which mysteriois hand kept scrolling me down. SE, please make this de facto off and make the text a bit more verbose..

Comment: I would love to do improve that behavior; unfortunately we have to support the iPhone :\ I can look at making some tweaks, but I'm not sure how much will work.

Comment: @balpha is it that different? I was wondering if it's a mobile jQuery limitation, but my iPad seems to run normal jQuery just fine...

Comment: Mobile Safari doesnt give you information about scroll position (at least not in iOS 4). If we had that, we could do the same thing the desktop version does: When you're on the bottom, stay there; if you've scrolled up, don't bother you. The "stay on bottom" thing is simply the manual way of making that distinction.

Comment: @balpha does iOS 5? iOS4 is basically the IE7 of iOS at this point

Comment: I haven't checked that yet. AFAIK, iOS 5 has some improvements in that area.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Stay on bottom" is dead.

I've spent some time improving the scrolling behavior (both in the mobile and the desktop version), and as part of this, I've managed to make it work on mobile devices without the user having to manually switch between "stay on bottom" and "let me scroll up" mode.

Comment: Awesome! Nice work

Comment: Seriously? :o That's amazing! :D

Comment: Nicely done!  Glad it's gone.

Comment: Oh, I am so happy... That mobile thing drove me nuts.